# Passing state from child to parent using hooks - React

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I want to pass the "filename" state from *child* component to the *parent* component. So that, I can use the "filename" state in the onSubmit function at parent. How can I achieve that? Currently filename at parent is not defined. Thanks a lot for your help.

Parent:

```
const AddLocation = ({ addLocation }) => {
  const initialFormState = { title: '', thumbnail: '' };
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(initialFormState);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setLocation({ ...location, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    addLocation({
      ...location,
      thumbnail: filename // I want to use filename state from child here.
    });
  };

  return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <TextInput
            id="add-loc-title"
            name="title"
            value={location.title}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <FileUpload />
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
  );
};
```

Child:

```
const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File');

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          id="add-cat-thumb"
          name="thumbnail"
          type="file"
          onChange={onChange}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Emit it as an event.  Props down, events up.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html . Nothing has really changed for hooks in this regard. Filename state can be moved to a parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle a state at Parent and pass the setState to the Child. Then call it on event.

Parent:

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState(''); // create a state as the parent

  const onSubmit = () => {
    addItem({
      ...item,
      file: filename
    });
  };
    
  return <FileUpload parentSetFile={setFile}/>
```

Then use `parentSetFile` in Child:

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
    props.parentSetFile(e.target.files[0]) // For Example
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };
```

**Edit after full code posted:**

So I assume you want the file will be updated in the parent after the submit succeeded, then you should do something like that:

Parent:

```
const AddLocation = ({ addLocation }) => {
  const initialFormState = { title: '', thumbnail: '' };
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [submittedFileName, setSubmittedFileName] = useState(null); // New state here to save the submitted file from child.

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setLocation({ ...location, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    addLocation({
      ...location,
      thumbnail: submittedFileName  // Use the submitted file name - a state handled in this component (Parent)
    });
  };

  return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <TextInput
            id="add-loc-title"
            name="title"
            value={location.title}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <FileUpload updateFileNameToParent={setSubmittedFileName} /> // Pass teh function that sets submittedFileName to the child so he could use it anyware he wants (probably after submit).
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
  );
};
```

Child:

```
const FileUpload = (props) => {  // Since this component now gets props, we should pass it here
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File');

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
    props.updateFileNameToParent(filename) // Call the function that sets submitedFileName for parent with the filename in the state of this component (Child)
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          id="add-cat-thumb"
          name="thumbnail"
          type="file"
          onChange={onChange}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I'm a little confused. If I do it like this, I get "filename is not defined" error. filename state is at child, do I need to define it at parent as well?

Comment: In case you want the state in the parent, you will need to handle that state at the parent. Now, if you are already handling the state at the parent, you can handle the same state at the child as well, but it won't be necessary since you can just pass it as a prop. I think i might not have enough information to figure out what is the cause of the error, can you share a codesandbox of that part of a code?

Comment: Now I pasted the complete parent and child codes to the original post. Thanks a lot for your sparing your time.

Comment: Edited with more details now, I marked the changes with comments. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is like this: Let's suppose you have a react component called < Parent > with state variable   fileName.  Let's suppose you need to run another react component called  < TheChild > from the  Parent's render function. Then, to use the  Parent's medthods, functions, state vars, etc. at TheChild you could pass the reference of the parent to the child as with:

```
   return( 
              ...
             <TheChild calledMe={this} />
              ...
   )
```

this will allow you to use  this.props.calledMe  within TheChild's code  to update the state of the Parent component as with:

```
this.props.calledMe.setState({fileName: .......}, () => {maybe do something else with fileName state variable})
```